# bash, how to dot source a downloaded file (using curl) into bash

Tags: bash, github, curl, dot-source

I have .sh file that I would like to dotsource into my running environment. This does not work:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh | bash
```

The above does not work, i.e. The script *runs*, but the environment variables and things inside `stuff.sh` are not dotsourced into the running environment. I also tried:

```
. curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh | bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh | bash source
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh | source bash
```

All fail. Would appreciate knowing how this can be done?

Comment: Use `source <(command)`

Comment: Thanks, but can't seem to get that to work: 
`$ source < (curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/bla/master/stuff.sh | bash) => bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`   `$ source < (curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/bla/master/stuff.sh) =>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`   `$ source < curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/bla/master/stuff.sh | bash => bash: curl: No such file or directory``

Comment: There should be no space between < and (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a bash expert, but if you are willing to accept some drawbacks, the easiest method to do that is without pipes. I believe that it should be possible when you separate download and sourcing:

```
prompt># curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh > ./stuff.sh
prompt># . ./stuff.sh
```

From the bash manual (`man bash`), in the chapter about the builtin `source` command:

> Read and execute commands from filename [...]

There is no mentioning about standard input as a possible source for the commands which should be sourced.

However, as hanshenrik stated in his answer, you always can use *process substitution* to create a temporary (and invisible on the file system) file which you can feed to `source`. The syntax is `<(list)`, where `<(list)` is expanded to a unique file name chosen by bash, and `list` is a sequence of commands whose output is put into that file (the file does not appear on the file system, though).

*Process substitution* is documented in the bash manual (`man bash`) in a paragraph under that exact caption.

Comment: ok, great, I was (wrongly) thinking that I might have to chmod the file after downloading it before I could run it, but this works. Perfect.

Comment: kvantour's solution is better, this approach has drawbacks: what happens if you have another script which is also using the filename "stuff.sh" for something? this will delete some other script. or what happens if the filesystem is read-only for some reason? this will fail.  kvantour's solution won't delete anything, and will work even if it's a read-only filesystem

Comment: I believe that it depends on circumstances which solution is better. For example, chances are that the OP needs that file not only one time; then having it stored would be better than downloading it again and again.

Comment: I want to do all of this actually, there are times that I want to overwrite the file and times that I'll do a `[ -f ./file ]` to check and times I just want to create without creating a file at all, so all very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try

```sh
source <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh)
```

i tried doing

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bla/bla/master/stuff.sh | source /dev/stdin
```

but that didn't work for some reason, no idea why (anyone knows?)

Comment: For future readers, the construct shown first in this answer is called *process substitution* and is documented in the bash manual (`man bash`) in a paragraph with exactly that caption.

Comment: The second contruct does not work because `source /dev/stdin` is run in a subshell.